Is there any way in html2Canvas to append elments but they should not be append on the browser?
I am using html2Canvas package to take the screenshot and I want to add some extra text in image but if i did this its also appending the text in my div /section tag and i don't want that text in that tag or reflect in browser. so there is any way i can add text without appending the text
const captureElement = document.querySelector("#result") as HTMLElement | null;  
    // Call the html2canvas function and pass the element as an argument
    if (captureElement) {
      html2canvas(captureElement).then((canvas) => {
        // Get the image data as a base64-encoded string
        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        
        // Do something with the image data, such as saving it as a file or sending it to a server
        // For example, you can create an anchor element and trigger a download action
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("download", "screenshot.png");
        link.setAttribute("href", imageData);
        link.click();
      });
    } else {
      console.error("Element #result not found")
  }


I tried to add text in image/div for taking screenshot using html2canvas but that text is appending in div and i don' want it I just want to add extra text in image but it should not affect the div tag
